# Go type for function call

Tags: go

Keywords like `go` and `defer` expect a *function call* as parameters. Is there a type available that can be used the same way? (e.g. to write a function that expects a function call - opposed to a function - as argument).

Comment: Interesting question. (+1ed) But what would you do with this, if it were possible?

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy the idea is to wrap the `go` keyword with some housekeeping.

Comment: I can see how that might be handy. And the parameter "freezing" you mention below could especially be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is not. You can't do the same with your function.

[`go`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements) and [`defer`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) are backed by the language spec and the rule is enforced by the compiler.

What you may do is use a variable / value of function type, which you may call later / at any time as if it would be a function.

For example:

```
func myFunc() {
    fmt.Println("hi")
}

func main() {
    var f func()
    f = myFunc
    f() // This calls the function value stored in f: myFunc in this example
}
```

**Edit:** To have the functionality you mentioned in the comment: just wrap the function call with its arguments in a `func()`, and use / pass that.

For example:

```
func launch(f func()) {
    fmt.Println("Before launch")
    go func() {
        defer fmt.Println("After completion")
        f()
    }()
}
```

Using it:

```
func main() {
    launch(func() {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    })

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AHLDrJyYQQn)):

```
Before launch
Hello, playground
After completion
```

Yes, this is not an exact workaround. If the params may change, you have to make a copy of them before calling `launch()`, and use the copy in the function literal (closure), like in this example:

```
s := "Hello, playground"

s2 := s // make a copy
launch(func() {
    fmt.Println(s2) // Use the copy
})
s = "changed"
```

#### Mimicing automatic parameter saving

For a concrete function type we may construct a helper function which provides us automatic parameter saving. This helper function must have identical signature, and return a function without parameters. The returned function is a closure which calls the original function with the parameters. The act of calling this helper function is the mechanism to save the parameters, so the usage is identical to that of `defer`.

For example the helper for `fmt.Println(s)` is:

```
func wrapPrintln(s string) func() {
    return func() {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
launch(wrapPrintln(s))
```

Example for a function with 2 `int` parameters:

```
func Sum(a, b int) {
    fmt.Println("Sum:", a+b)
}

func WrapSum(a, b int) func() {
    return func() {
        Sum(a, b)
    }
}

launch(WrapSum(a, b))
```

The above `WrapPrintln()` and `WrapSum()` wrapped a concrete function, and it can't be used for other functions (the wrapped function is "wired in"). We can make the wrapped functions a parameter too:

```
func WrapFuncIntInt(f func(a, b int), a, b int) func() {
    return func() {
        f(a, b)
    }
}
```

And we may use it like this:

```
launch(WrapFuncIntInt(Sum, a, b))
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-kNyfAQEbBg).

#### Using reflection to avoid the manual copies

You may use reflection to avoid having to make manual copies, but in this solution we're not actually calling the function, just passing it. Also due to using reflection, it will be slower. Another advantage is that this "feels" generic (we may use functions with different signatures), but we lose compile-time safety.

```
func launch(f interface{}, params ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("Before launch")
    go func() {
        defer fmt.Println("After completion")
        pv := make([]reflect.Value, len(params))
        for i, v := range params {
            pv[i] = reflect.ValueOf(v)
        }
        reflect.ValueOf(f).Call(pv)
    }()
}
```

Example calling it:

```
func main() {
    i, s := 1, "Hello, playground"

    launch(fmt.Printf, "%d %q\n", i, s)
    i, s = 2, "changed"

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ec7AJ015dPb)):

```
Before launch
1 "Hello, playground"
After completion
```

#### Single exception where you can utilize automatic parameter saving

There is a single exception which we may use. This is the [Method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values). If `x` has static type `T` and `T`'s [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) contains the method `M`, we may use `x.M` (without calling it).

The expression `x.M` is a method value, and it saves a copy of `x` which will be used as the receiver when the expression's result (which is a function value) is called.

Example:

```
type myParams struct {
    format string
    i int
    s string
}

func (mp myParams) Call() {
    fmt.Printf(mp.format, mp.i, mp.s)
}

func main() {
    p := myParams{format: "%d %q\n", i: 1, s: "Hello, playground"}
    launch(p.Call) // p is saved here
    p.i, p.s = 2, "changed"

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

func launch(f func()) {
    fmt.Println("Before launch")
    go func() {
        defer fmt.Println("After completion")
        f()
    }()
}
```

It outputs the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ez8FjT_Wj57).

Comment: Too bad. Feels like generics. (The language authors use it but you shouldn't).

Comment: The problem is with parameter evaluation, I'd like to freeze the actual parameter list just like go and defer does.

Comment: Wrapping my call inside a `func()` gives time for those args to change before `go` is executed.

Comment: @vbence Yes, this is not an exact workaround. If the params may change, you have to make a copy of them before calling `launch()`, and use the copy in the function literal (closure).

Comment: I think the error-proneness of manual copy would negate most of the upside. :-/

Comment: @vbence Yes. I've also presented another solution using reflection. It doesn't require manual copy, but it uses reflection. The "good" news is that it "feels" generic but loses compile-time safety.

Comment: @vbence There is a single exception where you can utilize automatic parameter saving yourself: method value. But it only saves a single parameter: the receiver. See edited answer.

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you. An automatically generated implicit struct for a method's parameter set would be a nice language feature (and pretty cheap too).

Comment: @vbence Added a new section **Mimicing automatic parameter saving** which provides automatic parameter saving for a concrete function type, keeping compile-time safety.